# ViewGroup container is null in onCreateView of a Fragment added with FragmentContainerView

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

**CONTEXT:**

I am using `FragmentContainerView` in order to add a `Fragment` in my XML.

I have feedback from testers, when they launch the App from `Background` state, the `Fragment` is not displayed.

To witness this bug, I have enabled the developer option "*Don't Keep Activites*".
Indeed, with this option, the `Fragment` is displayed properly during the first launch. Then, I put the App in the **background**, and launch it again -> `Fragment` is gone.

---

**CODE:**

Here is the XML with my `FragmentContainerView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainTileContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main_tile"
        android:name="com.app.fragment.FragmentMainTile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>

</FrameLayout>
```

The Fragment added inside the `FragmentContainerView` contains a `ViewPager` with a `TabLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/containerContraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/blurredConstraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blurred_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            style="@style/MyTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#084E92"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/blurredConstraintLayout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

With breakpoints inside the `onCreateView` method of my Fragment, the `ViewGroup` is my `FragmentContainerView` for the first launch, and is null after coming from background.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_container, container, false)
    }
```

I thought the `FragmentContainerView` would handle the Fragment operation for me :

> FragmentContainerView will perform a one time operation that:
>
> ```
> Creates a new instance of the Fragment
> Calls Fragment.onInflate(Context, AttributeSet, Bundle)
> Executes a FragmentTransaction to add the Fragment to the appropriate FragmentManager
> ```

Should I handle save/restore State within my Fragment? Can someone explains this behavior?

Comment: Are you overriding `onSaveInstanceState()` somewhere and forgetting to call `super.onSaveInstanceState()`? That is a common cause of fragments "disappearing" on you.

Comment: Also, the combination of a `wrap_content` parent with a `match_parent` child is suspicious. I wouldn't expect that to result in a null `container` argument, but still.

Comment: I'm not overriding `onSaveInstanceState`.  The combinaison of `wrap_content` in the parent with a `match_parent` child is because of my ViewPager. All the child `Fragments` in the `ViewPager` have specific height, and I want the parent container to resize accordingly.